# Disable Dev Mode in old version of GWT(2.1)

Tags: gwt

So I am checking old code from an app on GWT 2.1, when I compiled it with ant and try to check the page on Google Chrome i get the problem about old plugin blah blah update to new version and blah blah super dev mode.
I can change the version of gwt because reasons.  But I cant find old documentation about gwt on dev mode, just new one and they talk about super dev mode. 
How do you disable dev mode on old versions of GWT.

Comment: Remove "?gwt.codeserv=" from the url and try again

Comment: yeap thanks, i am new to gwt

Comment: Happy to help. GWT is a nice technology bu very niche. If you can try to update to a more recent version, Super Dev Mode (as opposed to the Classic Dev Mode, the one with the plugin) will make your life much better.